# Set target/action of a UITableViewCell subview inside the UITableViewController, without a storyboard

Tags: storyboard, uitableview, target-action

With a storyboard, you can easily customise a cell, with subviews, and insert actions of those subviews, directly inside the table controller, via `- (IBAction)handle:(id)sender;`
But is it possible to do something similar, without a storyboard or a nib ?
I have a custom cell, and a custom table controller.

- I can't insert the action inside the cell implementation, because it's supposed to trigger stuff from the controller.
- I can use UIGesture inside the controller, at `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, but every time it's called, it will insert a gesture for the cell. Of course, I can manage this...

So I wonder if there is a "simple" way to implement the action of a cell's subview inside the table controller, like the IBAction, without a storyboard or a nib ?
Thanks.
B.R.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a custom tableViewCell, you can add an `UITapGestureRecognizer` to that view.

You have to make a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and implement the `- awakeFromNib` Method. There you can add the gesture recognizer to the view inside the cell.

It's not a complete solution, but it could be a good point to start.

Comment: The thing is, I don't have a storyboard or a nib. I'd like to do everything programmatically.
So if I put the tap implementation inside the custom cell class, I can not trigger stuff from the table controller class, like : present a new controller...

Comment: I would recommend creating a NIB file with a single tableViewCell. Than you can use `[UITableView registerNib:forReusableIdentifier:];`. When you then use `- dequeCellForReusaleIdentifier:`, you NIB gets loaded and setup. In the NIB you make a prototype for the cell, add the recognizer and connect outlets and so on. This is the BEST practice.

Comment: I just read this again and thought I could add some info. If you really don't want to use Nibs you can also register your custom class and do everything programmatically in the class. You then implement a protocol for the cell and set your controller as delegate of the cell in `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`